# Disabling or mocking Spring Security filters while integration testing RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, integration-testing

In my app I've got a custom filter added in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extension:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/**");

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);

        // filter setup...

        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }
}
```

The filter itself, which is responsible for validating the access token by calling an external authorization server is defined as:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    AuthenticationFilter(final RequestMatcher requiresAuth) {
        super(requiresAuth);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, OAuth2Exception {
        try {
            // Get Authorization header.
            String token = httpServletRequest.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);

            // Check if the token is valid by calling an external authorization server.
            // Returns some Authentication if successful.
        } catch (OAuth2Exception exception) {
            // Return 401
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            // All other errors are 500s
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                            final HttpServletResponse response,
                                            final FilterChain chain,
                                            final Authentication authResult)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to perform integration test on the controller defined as:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1", produces = "application/json")
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @ResponseStatus(OK)
    @PostMapping(value = "/a/path")
    public SomeSuccessResponse pathHandlerMethod() {
        return someService.someServiceMethod();
    }
}
```

Finally, my test setup is as following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SomeController.class)
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SomeControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @MockBean
    private SomeService someService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity()) // When I comment out this line I'm getting 404 errors instead.
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void performIntegrationTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/a/path")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

I'd like the authentication to be either turned off or somehow mocked out for this scenario - the actual code in `AuthenticationFilter` sholdn't be invoked at all. In order to achieve this, in `SomeControllerTest` class I've tried:

- annotating test methods with `@WithMockUser`
- setting `mockMvc` with `MockMvcBuilders` (see the `setup()` method above) with `.apply(springSecurity())` and without it
- annotating the `SomeControllerTest` class with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` (with both `secure` and `addFilters` parameters set to `false`)
- annotating the `SomeControllerTest` class with `@ContextConfiguration` and `@WebAppConfiguration` (I don't know if it changes anything)

None of these approaches disable the authentication. When I run the test, the `AuthenticationFilter`'s `attemptAuthentication()` method calling external service is still invoked which I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the filter sounds contradictory for an integration test, imho. Have you considered mocking the filter instead?

Create a

```
public class MockAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
   // return mock data for different use cases. 
}
```

Then register this filter in your test.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
        .apply(springSecurity(new MockAuthenticationFilter()))
        .build();
```

}

This would also allow you to test different use cases where the filter acts one way or an other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After implementing an empty mock authentication filter and attaching it to mockMvc, I keep getting 404s now.